# I cannot omit fig1 above a figure

Tags: floats

I insert

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{figure 1.png}
\end{center}
\caption{First question}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

and the figure and title are appeared correctly but above the figure is appeared 1.png.

How can i omit this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not post fragments of code only. Always provide a `\documentclass{...}` and a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` such that users can test and help quicker

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics{"figure 1.png"}
\caption{First question}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```